# Footer in Web page displays as inline element rather than block element

Tags: html, css

Beginner with HTML here. I've been getting a pretty funky error with my HTML script. When I display it, the footer looks it was formatted like an inline element. It is showing up on the side of my timeline rather than at the bottom of the page.

Here is a screen shot:
[Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbRT9.png)

Here is the code:

```
 <DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>About Mangetsu Budogu</title>
        <style>
        /*Total Body width must be greater than widths for content */
        /*global scope css */
            body{
                width: 1080px;
                font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
                color: #665544; 
                }
            .main_content{
                float: left;
                width: 620px;
                margin: 10px;
                }
        /* Nav Bar CSS */
            nav {
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                border-radius: 25px;
                width: 99%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            nav a{
                float: center;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            nav a:hover{
                background-color: red;
                }
            nav li{
                display: inline;
                padding: 5px;
            }


        /* Timeline */
            .timeline{
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
                margin: 10px;
                }

            li{
                margin: 10px 0;
                }
        /* Main Content*/
        #main_heading{
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
        }
        footer { 
            display: block;
        }
        </style>

        </head>

        <header>
            <center><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Sakai_Kamon.svg" width="200" height="200"/></center>
            <nav>
                <ul id="nav_li">
                 <li><a href="http://www.hawkeyekendo.com/home">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="https://www.hawkeyekedo.com/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../../test">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../Classes">Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>

        <body>
            <h1 id="main_heading">About Mangetsu Budogu</h1>
            <article class="main_content">

                <h2>Beginnings</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Praesent posuere felis non turpis venenatis porta. Ut vel ultrices ipsum, vel blandit ipsum. Fusce rhoncus eget mauris ut pellentesque. Aenean condimentum lacus aliquam tristique efficitur. Nam commodo mattis dolor id molestie. Nulla molestie, magna suscipit gravida placerat, tortor libero faucibus risus, ac lacinia lacus metus at ex. Integer auctor sollicitudin quam, in gravida diam rhoncus non. Praesent lacinia velit est, et efficitur velit lobortis quis. Donec eleifend gravida sem aliquet finibus. Duis tempus, orci vel blandit luctus, sem sapien rhoncus enim, eu consequat ex mauris posuere augue. Etiam mi sem, scelerisque sit amet dictum eget, eleifend id urna. Fusce non condimentum dui, vel rhoncus nisl. Sed lacinia dui non lacinia mollis. Maecenas sodales lorem et est sodales molestie.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Nam et ipsum ac est ornare mattis. Mauris aliquet consequat lorem id lacinia. Nunc vulputate mollis bibendum. Duis sed enim a turpis mollis consectetur vitae vel mi. Phasellus quis lectus velit. Morbi vel libero pulvinar tortor placerat placerat. Suspendisse id ante leo. Etiam eu facilisis enim. Cras lorem tellus, bibendum eget turpis vitae, porta blandit lorem. Nam ut dui eu mauris malesuada ultricies. Cras nec erat dictum, ultricies sem non, vestibulum arcu. Fusce varius imperdiet nulla eu convallis. Curabitur quis mattis felis, non pretium ex.   </p>

                <h2>The 1990s Era</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent posuere felis non turpis venenatis porta. Ut vel ultrices ipsum, vel blandit ipsum. Fusce rhoncus eget mauris ut pellentesque. Aenean condimentum lacus aliquam tristique efficitur. Nam commodo mattis dolor id molestie. Nulla molestie, magna suscipit gravida placerat, tortor libero faucibus risus, ac lacinia lacus metus at ex. Integer auctor sollicitudin quam, in gravida diam rhoncus non. Praesent lacinia velit est, et efficitur velit lobortis quis. Donec eleifend gravida sem aliquet finibus. Duis tempus, orci vel blandit luctus, sem sapien rhoncus enim, eu consequat ex mauris posuere augue. Etiam mi sem, scelerisque sit amet dictum eget, eleifend id urna. Fusce non condimentum dui, vel rhoncus nisl. Sed lacinia dui non lacinia mollis. Maecenas sodales lorem et est sodales molestie.
                </p>
            </article>
            <div class="timeline">
                <h3>Mangetsu Budogu Timeline</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><time>1991</time>: Established Flagship Store in <strong>Kyoto, Japan, Nishijin District</strong></li>
                    <li>1995: Created first Kendogu Website in Japan</li>
                    <li>1997: Establishment of 2nd Store in <strong>Shinagawa District, Tokyo</strong></li>
                    <li>1999: Creation of the Mangetsu Budogu Reward Points</li>
                    <li>2001: Establishment of 3rd Store in <strong>Nakamura District, Nagoya</strong></li>
                    <li>2010: Creation of the Shingsengumi Line of Bogu</li>
                    <li>2011: First Overseas Store in Los Angeles, California</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <footer>
            &copy; Mangetsu Budogu 2018
        </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: because you are floating your timeline. You have to clear your float if you want the footer below it. Also `center` is not a valid value from `float` fyi

Comment: Your `html` declaration is not correct you're missing the `!` btw `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @Adam. It's missing because of a bad cut and paste, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float property you have assigned to `<article class="main_content">` and `<div class="timeline">`. Just add this element before `footer`.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.main_content` and the `timeline` are floating elements which don't span the whole width of the body, that's why the footer is displayed next to it (it "floats" next to the floating elements).

To avoid this, add `clear: both` to the `footer` CSS